# Who, when, and why invented the symmetric derivative?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, math-history

When computing an approximate derivative of a function on a computer, engineers use the [symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) for reduced error.

Who came up with the symmetric derivative? Who proved it? When?
Why was it originally invented?

Comment: I have got the feeling this question is better suited for [History of Math and Science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's a by-product of [Finite Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference), [Divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference),  interpolation polynomials, ....

Comment: Does it have anything to do with M.V. Ostrogradskii?